# Pagerank existence of a graph given a vector (refined)

Tags: linear-algebra

I previously [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368043/pagerank-existence-of-a-graph-given-a-vector) with nonspecific restrictions that resulted in a trivial solution, so I'm back with more restrictions on the problem!

Given a vector $x\in \mathbb {R}^n, x_i\ge0,\sum x_i = 1,$find a matrix $A \in \mathbb {R}^{n \times n}$ with the following restrictions:

- $A$ is a column-stochastic matrix, so $\sum_i{A_{ij}=1}$ for all j
- $A_{ii} = 0$ for all i
- $Ax = x$, so an eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda = 1$,
- the dimension of the eigenvalue's eigenspace $V_1(A)=1$

In terms of Pagerank's representation in graph theory, this equates to finding a set of directed edges between nodes such that the enumerated nodes' Pageranks correspond to the vector $x$.

The second restriction stated above is to ensure that the trivial solution, where A is

My solution so far does not converge. I measure convergence by taking the L2 norm of the difference between the current Pagerank of all nodes and the desired Pagerank of those nodes. I've been using a guess-and-check approximation method that involves donating Pagerank to a specific page from other pages that already have more Pagerank than their desired amount. The first iteration is the most effective (original L2 norm is 18% off and it brings it down to 0.1%), but due to some bug, future iterations diverge from the solution.

Rather than ask the math community to debug my code, I'm asking to see if anyone can mathematically describe the process for a candidate solution. I assume that a reasonable solution will be power-method based, but I'm not awfully well-versed in devising mathematical solutions for myself -- I'm a computer science student with a bit of math background.